# How can I use a for loop over distinct strings in R?

Tags: r

I have a data table (df) with a column (disease) listed with strings (words) instead of integers. I've been trying to use a for loop to loop over the distinct strings, but I end up with an i value of just 1 each time. How can I get this code to work?

```
for(i in unique(df, disease))
{
  print(i)
  fun(df, i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to index into your "disease"

```
    uniqDisease <- unique(df, disease)
    funout <- vector('list') # initialize
    for (jj in 1:length(uniqDisease)) {
    print(uniqDisease[jj]
# to get all the values returned, need to collect the output of "fun"
    funout[[jj]] <-  fun(df,uniqDisease[jj])
    }
```

Comment: it seemed to work, but is only outputting for one of the unique strings. Is it possible to store each new changed data frame into its own, with the name based on jj?

Comment: `R` returns only the last value calculated.  See my edit

Comment: After seeing the output, it only shows one of 29 other diseases. Will the data with the 29 other diseases be stored too?